# PFQueryTableView Breaking at loadView

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, tableview, pfquery

I'm implementing a `PFQueryTableView` controller via storyboard. I've followed the right methods in actually implementing the code (using `initWithCoder:`). But whenever I try to run the app it breaks at the `PFQueryTableViewController.m` file; specifically at the `loadView` method. It breaks at `[super loadView]`. Anyone else encounter this problem?

Edit: When I remove the breakpoint I get the following error: `2015-02-10 14:31:52.208 TokenApp[1234:27812] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "94a-xH-nEI-view-RYC-1K-mIS" nib but didn't get a UITableView.`

I'm think it's complaining because it's wanting a nib, but I'm not actually using a nib.

Comment: Is it a breakpoint (`EXC_BREAKPOINT`) or is it actually crashing? Can you please post your code, a stack trace, and any error messages you're seeing?

Comment: One shot-in-the-dark guess: perhaps you have exception breakpoints turned on, and they have some try/catch block in there that's catching something.

Comment: Updated with proper error above.

Comment: Does your storyboard have a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: I'm using a UIViewController with a tableview set on top of it... I'm guessing therein lies the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root view of your view controller needs to be a `UITableView`.

You can recreate your controller using the `UITableViewController` template.

Alternatively, you can manually edit your `.storyboard` file and change the relevant `<view …>` and `</view>` tags to say `<tableView…` and `</tableView>`. Just make sure you have a backup or your file is under version control.